# How to keep an activity alive after back button press?

Tags: android, android-activity, chromecast, lifecycle

I'm developing a chromecast streaming app for Android. In Activity A the user chooses between different playable items and then is moved to Activity B, which holds the Chromecast controls. When the user hits the back button he is presented with Activity A from where he can choose another video while the casting of the first one is still running on the TV. The problem is that after the back button is pressed, Activity B which holds the controls (for example: seek bar with the video progress) is destroyed and there is no way the user can interact with the destroyed controls anymore. Is there a way I can keep Activity B alive? I'm a novice developer and I have no experience with fragments, so I'm looking for a solution which does not involve their usage...

Comment: Maybe you can create a Fragment that connects to the streaming Service.
Then you can recreate the fragment at any time with the reference to the service.

Comment: don't. use a service, that's what they are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you read the [Cast UX Checklist](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist) where this issue is brought up and addressed. The ways to address that are:

- Having a [persistent controller](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist#sender-persistent-control) on each page
- Using the [Media Router Controller Dialog](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist#sender-cast-menu-casting) when casting
- When not in the application but casting, using [Notification](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist#sender-control-notification)
- When on the lock screen, using the [Lock Screen media controller buttons](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist#sender-control-lockscreen)

On Android, you can use the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) that provides all of these for you with minimal coding.

Comment: Thanks Naddaf! The CCL is a great library which saved me a lot of work. Now I'm trying to style some of the components to match my app's theme. I've copied the mini_controller.xml into my project's resources and did some modifications to the styling with no problem. However, when I try to do the same with the custom_notification.xml the changes I'm applying have no effect at all. How can I style the notification dialog?

Comment: What kind of styling are you trying to do?

Comment: Just some background/text coloring.

Comment: Notifications in the recent version of CCL are completely handled by NotificationCompat library (the style is it is MediaStyle) so I shoud remember to remove the layout xml files that are in CCL since they are not used anymore. So styling of the notification is done by the NotificationCompat and you need to see how that can be styled for your app in general (through your custom theme, for example). I haven't done that so I don't know what level of styling is available.

Comment: FYI: just asked a friend who knows about styling in NotificationCompat and he said we cannot change the text color.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the streaming without any UI showing, you need to create a `Service` and bind to it with your activities. Let the service handle everything. Like this you're not dependent on the UI being shown.